# Ricci curvature and killing form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Motivated by [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31198/curvature-of-a-lie-group) we ask:

> Is there any relation between the Ricci curvature of  a  Lie  group and the killing form of its  Lie algebra?Under what conditions, they are proportional to each other?

Comment: See Section 7 of Milnor's "Curvatures of Left Invariant Metrics on Lie Groups": http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870876800023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Lie group is compact and semisimple, then the Killing form $B$ is negatively definite and $-B$ defines a bi-invariant metric. Its Ricci curvature is
$$Ric(X)=-\frac{1}{4}\sum_{i=2}^nB(\left[X,e_i\right],\left[X,e_i\right])$$
for any $B$-orthonormal base $\left\{e_1=X,e_2,\ldots,e_n\right\}$ with $e_1=X$. In particular, $Ric(X)$ is nonnegative.